# Make a UITableViewCell Coloured to specific percentage

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, background-color, uicolor

I have an app quiz app split up into different categories. The categories can be seen in a UITableView e.g. Category A, Category B, Category C...etc. I am trying to show the percentage of questions that have been answered as a visual representation in the UITableView by colouring the background of a category UITableView cell.

For example if the person has completed 75% of the questions in category A, I want the background of category A in the UITableView to be coloured in a green colour 75% of the background of the Cell from left to right.

The only way would know how to do it is to make background images of a green background and depending on the percentage of questions answered place the relating background image as the background for the cell background.

Is there an easier way? that I could possibly use something like

```
Cell.backgroundcolor = UIColor.greencolor().75%ofCell.
```

I know this code isn't correct but it Kind of gets the idea across of what I am trying to do.

Comment: can you show us design ? What do you want actually /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it without adding a view to you cell by using a layer:

In your cell class you could add the following function:

```
func addGradientLayer(percentage: Double) {
   let color1 = UIColor.green
   let color2 = UIColor.clear

   let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
   // sets the gradient frame as the bounds of your cell
   gradientLayer.frame = bounds 

   gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]

   // tells the gradient to go from left to right
   gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5) 
   gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

   //this line is the important one: as 
   //long the second Double is smaller than 
   //your percentage, you will not get a gradient 
   //but a clear separation between your two colors.
   gradientLayer.locations = [percentage, 0.0]

   layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

you can then call this method within your awakeFromNib() method or in cellForRowAt (tableView delegate):

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   ...
   cell.addGradientLayer(percentage: 0.8)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using storyboards, add a `UIView` with `backgroundColor = .greenColor()` to the cell

Add top, left and bottom constrains for the view equal to the superview, then add a *width* constraint for the view and create an outlet for it.

Then in the cell you can say:

```
var pctScore: CGFloat {
   didSet {
       let viewWidth = cell.contentView.frame.width * pctScore
       widthConstraint.constant = viewWidth
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add a UIView as subview to the cell and make the background color of the UIView the color that you want.

Before adding the view you set the views width to 0.75 * cellWidth.